# Start chrome & firefox with proxy using webdriverio in nodejs

Tags: node.js, proxy, webdriver-io

How can I open a browser session with proxy set through the options(/desired capabilities) using WebDriverIO in NodeJs. I use this code for setting proxy, but it stopped working. The browser opens without the proxy and will not perform any further actions.

```js
options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        proxy: {
            proxyType: 'manual',
            httpProxy: '127.0.0.11:80'
        }
    }
};

client = webdriverio.remote(options).init();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code should work:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');


    var options = {
        desiredCapabilities: { 
            browserName: 'firefox'
            , proxy: {
                proxyType: 'MANUAL'
                , httpProxy: '127.0.0.11:80'

            }
        } 
    };

client = webdriverio.remote(options).init();
```

Reference: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/324